# get value after certain character in URL bar

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get `this_value` out of `example.com/#/this_value/something/something...`.

How I know how to get 'user' and 'admin'?

```
example.com/#/user
example.com/#/admin
```

but it seems like I have to use regex because the url may look like this

```
example.com/#/user/something/something_more
```

Comment: `\/#\/(\w+)` ............

Comment: How are you getting the urls? window.location? link? plain text?

Comment: Please add some real code. Is this the `href` value of an `a` element? Is it the current location (`window.location`)? Is this something you have in a string variable? What have you tried, and where did you run into problems? If you are looking at `window.location`or an `a` element, there is an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## If your URLs are the URL of the page you're currently on

`window.location.hash` will give you the `#/user/...` and `#/admin/...` parts. From that you can use call `split` on the `/` character to give you an array like:

```
["#", "user", "something", "something_more"]
```

From that you can just grab the `[1]` index from that array. You can do this all in one line:

```
window.location.hash.split('/')[1]
```

**Examples**

```js
"example.com/#/user"
-> "user"
```

```js
"example.com/#/admin"
-> "admin"
```

```js
"example.com/#/user/something/something_more"
-> "user"
```

## If your URLs are just strings

If they're strings and not URLs, `window.location` won't help much here. Instead we can apply `split` directly to the string itself, but remember to jump the pulled index up by one to cater for the `/` before the `#` character.

**Examples**

```
var example = "example.com/#/user";
example.split('/')[2];
-> "user"
```

```js
var example = "example.com/#/admin";
example.split('/')[2];
-> "admin"
```

```js
var example = "example.com/#/user/something/something_more";
example.split('/')[2];
-> "user"
```